# How to fix the error in MATLAB solving for symbolic variable

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I'm trying to find the eigenvalues of a system depending on a change in flow velocity. I have set up my equation to solve for alpha in terms of omega (omega is the eigenvalues) then I need to set the determinate of the alpha matrix (which I have named delta) to zero to solve for omega. However, I am receiving an error when setting up the matrix delta, specifically at delta(2,1:4) = alpha. The error is "Unable to perform assignment because value of type 'sym' is not convertible to 'double'." I don't want to substitute in a random number however because that is what I am solving for!

Here's my code:

```
%Set variables
B = 0.1; %Beta
u_cr = 10; %set critical velocity
u_array = [0.1:0.1:u_cr]; %Range of velocities
sym omega %Set omega to solve
m = 1; %initialize u array
q = 19; %initialize loop
delta = zeros(4);
real = zeros(1,q);
imaginary = zeros (1,q);

for j = 1:q
    u = u_array(m);
    F = [1 u^2 0 -2*(B^1/2)*u*omega -omega]; 
    alpha = (roots(F)).';
    delta(1,1:4) = 1;
    delta(2,1:4) = alpha;
    delta(3,1:4) = alpha.^2.*exp(1i.*alpha);
    delta(4,1:4) = alpha.^3.*exp(1i.*alpha);
    det(delta) = 0;
    real(m) = real(omega);
    imaginary(m) = imag(omega);
    m = m+1;
end
```

Any suggestions on how to solve for omega and fix the error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of `delta = zeros(4);` you have to make sure that `delta` is a symbolic matrix instead of double, by doing `delta = sym(zeros(4));`.